# rtmp push stream not smooth

Tags: rtmp, smoothing

I use librtmp push a video stream,but not smooth. It's very complex, as described in detail below

**conditions:**

- the process run on iphone, needs two iphones, one for capture, named A, another for push rtmp, named B, codec use hard codec.
- A sends H264 data to B by UDP, it use apple's operate api MCSession, I guarantee that no data have been discard
- just push video, fps=24 gop=2, timestamp is smooth, like:

  2017-02-08 19:34:15.085419[1798:333259] video pts:0 datalen:23749 count:0
  2017-02-08 19:34:15.089538 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:41 datalen:960 count:1
  2017-02-08 19:34:15.090579 Demo[1798:333277] [INFO][send_thread-1115]: I Get a video keyframe.
  2017-02-08 19:34:15.097951 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:83 datalen:389 count:2
  2017-02-08 19:34:15.144360 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:166 datalen:1202 count:3
  2017-02-08 19:34:15.573635 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:208 datalen:1359 count:4
  2017-02-08 19:34:15.573866 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:249 datalen:542 count:5
  2017-02-08 19:34:15.605937 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:291 datalen:2610 count:6
  2017-02-08 19:34:15.606247 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:333 datalen:1520 count:7
  2017-02-08 19:34:15.611275 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:374 datalen:5586 count:8
  2017-02-08 19:34:15.611502 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:416 datalen:2461 count:9
  2017-02-08 19:34:15.612747 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:499 datalen:9176 count:10
  2017-02-08 19:34:15.612819 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:541 datalen:159 count:11
  2017-02-08 19:34:15.651997 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:583 datalen:6309 count:12
  2017-02-08 19:34:15.655453 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:624 datalen:2961 count:13
  2017-02-08 19:34:15.733225 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:666 datalen:10945 count:14
  2017-02-08 19:34:15.742729 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:708 datalen:71 count:15
  2017-02-08 19:34:16.112011 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:791 datalen:4969 count:16
  2017-02-08 19:34:16.113968 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:833 datalen:2444 count:17
  2017-02-08 19:34:16.136762 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:874 datalen:9232 count:18
  2017-02-08 19:34:16.137038 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:916 datalen:304 count:19
  2017-02-08 19:34:16.139052 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:958 datalen:9484 count:20
  2017-02-08 19:34:16.139313 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:999 datalen:167 count:21
  2017-02-08 19:34:16.139797 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:1083 datalen:5598 count:22
  2017-02-08 19:34:16.167673 Demo[1798:333259] video pts:1124 datalen:9554 count:23

### **problem:**

- after B received data, I packet it and use librtmp push it in a new thread, sometimes it's ok, but some times it's not smooth. I found that the socket send function takes a long time, when my video buffer is full, I discard video data. But the current network environment is ok, because the same time A push rtmp is ok. rtmp server is ali cdn.
- If B push rtmp to simple rtmp server, it always works ok.

I do not know what causes the send data to time out when I push to ali cdn.

Comment: pls refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting your query

Comment: thank you, i will edit it again.